# URL - Unix timestamp doubt

Tags: cron, wordpress

/?doing_wp_cron=1515663000.7121028900146484375000

this is appended automatically in my url. I know about the first part. i.e 1515663000. which denotes the unix timestamp of 11/01/2018 9:30AM. what about the second one i.e. after the period. (7121028900146484375000)

Answer (score 1):

This is a Wordpress function which uses a timestamp in seconds and [microseconds](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php), cast to 22 decimal places. See [this code reference](https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/wordpress-azure/blob/master/wp-cron.php) for the detail.

Empirically it seems that casting a timestamp to 22 digits adds pseudo-random junk to the least significant part:

```
x=$(date +%s.%N)    # %N is nanoseconds, 9 digits. Microseconds would be
                    # 6 digits but the principle is similar enough

printf "%s -- %.22F\n" "$x" "$x"
1515706488.768975900 -- 1515706488.7689759000204503536224
```

---

As an aside, the human-readable date "11/01/2018" as written in your question is ambiguous. In some parts of the world it reads as you (and I) would consider "01/11/2018". Furthermore the time part (and actually, potentially the date too) will vary depending on your time zone. For that reason it would be better to describe 1515663000 as being equivalent to "11 Jan 2018 09:30:00 UTC".

Comment: The 0.7121028900146484375000 part has 22 decimal places, while a nano-second only has 9 places.   OTOH, the 146484375 portion might be an embedded date from 2016.

Comment: @DMcKeon good catch. Answer amended

Comment: Even more locale independent would be using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (perhaps using spaces for readability), with the additional advantage that it is alphabetically sortable: `2018-01-11 09:30:00 +00:00`

Comment: @Murphy programmatically I almost always use YYYY-MM-DD and HH:mm:ss (UTC) for my dates and times. These avoid language/locale issues. For "conversational" dates with people outside my country I tend to use their timezone (and reference as "your time"), but never an unqualified 1/2/2018 format date.